# Randomly picked names displayed in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Ok so i have an array of names to be picked from randomly to be display in a text area called "textbox". It works with math.random() but will only pick a new random name when i reload the page. How would i get it to pick a new random name every time somebody clicks the button, so that they don't have to reload the page?

```
<p id="textbox"></p>
<button onclick="generateFunction()"> Generate </button>

<script>
function generateFunction() {
  var Names = ["Alex", "Alan", "Bob"];
  var displayNames = Names[Math.floor(Math.random() * Names.length)];

  document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML = displayNames;
}
```

Comment: That snippet has syntax error. Missing `()` for the function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite correct. But it has syntax errors.

- First, It's missing `()` in the markup and script.
- Second, You haven't declared the function before you called the function. It's like trying to calling the value of a variable that hasn't been initialized.

This would be the correct code:

```
<script type=text/javascript">
    function generateFunction {
        var Names = ["Alex", "Alan", "Bob"];
        var displayNames = Names[Math.floor(Math.random() * Names.length)];

        document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML = displayNames;
    }
</script

<p id="textbox"></p>
<button onclick="generateFunction"> Generate </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a new name in every click, you will have to check whether the name is same as the displayed one if so need to regenerate it.

You can use a simple loop statement to do that like

```js
function generateFunction() {
  var Names = ["Alex", "Alan", "Bob"],
    existing = document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML.trim(),
    displayNames;
  do {
    displayNames = Names[Math.floor(Math.random() * Names.length)]
  } while (displayNames == existing)


  document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML = displayNames;
}
```

```html
<p id="textbox"></p>
<button onclick="generateFunction()">Generate</button>
```